# Onclick Javascript button: How to use IN where clause in SOQL query in Javascript?

Tags: soql, javascript

I have a Javascript button, I need to check the number of records having same Owner ID through a SOQL aggregate query. ActIds contains the all selected Activity__c records IDs

```
var ActIds = [];

var AggregateResult_Owner = sforce.connection.query("SELECT OwnerId, count(Id) FROM Activity__c WHERE Id IN  (\'' + ActIds .join('\',\'') + '\')  GROUP BY OwnerId");
```

On click of  button, this query is throwing an error 'MALFORMED QUERY'

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: From where is the `ActIds` array been set with the values

Answer (score 2):

You can create a String by iterating over the `AccIds` array in Javascript and then you can add that string into the SOQL query in the where clause

```
var selectedAccIds=''; 
for(var i=0;i < ActIds.length; i++)
{
    selectedAccIds+="'"+ActIds[i]+"',";
}
selectedAccIds = selectedAccIds.substring(0,selectedAccIds.length - 1);

var queryStr = "SELECT OwnerId, count(Id) FROM Activity__c WHERE Id IN ("+selectedAccIds+") GROUP BY OwnerId"; 

var AggregateResult_Owner = sforce.connection.query(queryStr);
```